# geometry of Automorphism groups

Tags: complex-geometry

It is proved that Aut group of a compact complex manifold is a lie transformation group.

How do we show that a automorphism group of a tubular geometry is a lie group?

Comment: What is tubular geometry? I never heard of it.

Comment: Do you mean to refer to *toric varieties*?